# Why am I getting "Unknown Name..." name error when calling the Google Sheets API?

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to duplicate a sheet using the Google Sheets API. I've been successful reading and writing variables, but I'm stuck on the `DuplicateSheetRequest` with `batchUpdate()` code. My code looks like this:

```
requests = []
requests.append({
    "DuplicateSheetRequest": {
        "sourceSheetId": sheet_id_source,
        "insertSheetIndex": target_index,
        "newSheetId": 123456,
        "newSheetName": destination_sheet_name
    }
})
body = {
    'requests': requests
}
response = service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=spreadsheetId,
                                           body=body).execute()
```

When I execute the code, I get an error:

> https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/[sheet ID redacted]:batchUpdate?alt=json returned "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "duplicate_sheet_request" at 'requests[0]': Cannot find field.">

What's really odd is that the error says `"duplicate_sheet_request"` whereas my code says `DuplicateSheetRequest`. (I also tested something I knew was wrong, e.g. `"DuplicateSheetRequestsss"`, which became `"duplicate_sheet_requestsss"`). I don't know why the variable name is chasing, though I'm inclined to believe this is a red herring.

The closest thing I could find is [this Google Groups issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=5461) that suggests that perhaps the method I'm trying to use isn't allowed with a service account, but I may be misreading that thread.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the batch update method I was looking for should have been `duplicateSheet`, not `DuplicateSheetRequest`:

```
requests.append({
    "duplicateSheet": {
        "sourceSheetId": sheet_id_source,
        "insertSheetIndex": target_index,
        #"newSheetId": 123456,
        "newSheetName": destination_sheet_name
    }
})
```

Quack quack.